# How to keep last dynamic value of variable in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I randomly create email address and assert it after created. Therefore I need the value of email address.
For that purpose, I defined `Cypress.env('emailAddress', randomEmail)` variable.
But I can't keep and use it for assertion.
My question is:
**How to keep the dynamic value of variable in cypress?**

```
    let randomText = ''
    let testEmail =''
    var pattern = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstyvwxyz'
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    randomText+=pattern.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * pattern.length)) 
    testEmail = randomText + '@gmail.com'
    Cypress.env('emailS', testEmail)
    cy.typeCommand(selector, String(testEmail))
```

And this is the assertion:

```
cy.isContain('[data-test="item-undefined-email"]', Cypress.env('emailS'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress environment variables are kept between tests in the same spec file. In order to start your run without a variable, you can set the value as undefined in the `afterEach()` portion of your tests.

```js
describe('tests', () => {
  ...
  afterEach(() => {
    Cypress.env('emailAddress', undefined);
  })
})
```

Comment: Now, it looks for "undefined" to contain.

Comment: My best guess is that the `cy.typeCommand` is getting executed before the `Cypress.env` is set. Can you try wrapping the email creation in a function, and then doing `cy.wrap(myFunc()).then((email) => { Cypress.env('emailS', email) }).typeCommand()`?